# How to get a list of files using Apache ANT

Tags: ant

I am basically looking to convert

```
array=($(find /foo/bar/ -name class.java))
```

into ant script .

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a [`fileset`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html):

```
<fileset dir="/foo/bar" includes="**/class.java" id="java.files" />
```